# Evaluate $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2} \left[ \prod_{j=1}^k (1+t+\dots+t^{d_j -1}) \right]$ at $t=1$

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, analysis, polynomials, derivatives

I need to find a "nice" formula for the evaluation of 
$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2} \left[ \prod_{j=1}^k (1+t+\dots+t^{d_j -1}) \right]$ at t=1, where $d_j \in \mathbb{N}$.

I have already proved that 
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \left[ \prod_{j=1}^k (1+t+\dots+t^{d_j -1}) \right]_{| t=1} =\frac{1}{2} \cdot \prod_{i=1}^k d_i \cdot \left[ \sum_{i=1}^k d_i -k \right]
\end{equation}

and now I'm looking for a similar concise formula for the second derivative at t=1.

Comment: How did you derive the formula for the first derivative?

Comment: The [general Leibniz Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule) may help. You'll need to generalize it to products of more than two terms, but it's not hard to see how that should work.

Comment: @Alizter I derived the formula for the first derivative in the following way:\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \left[ \prod_{j=1}^k (1+t+\dots+t^{d_j -1}) \right] =\sum_{i=1}^k \left[ \prod_{j\neq 1} (1+t+\dots+t^{d_j -1}) \right] (1+2t+\dots+(d_i-1) t^{d_i -2})
\end{equation}
Evaluate at t=1 and you get
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^k \left[ \left( \prod_{j \neq i} d_j \right) \frac{d_i(d_i -1)}{2} \right]= \prod_{i=1}^k d_i \cdot \left( \sum_{i=1}^k \frac{d_i -1}{2} \right) = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \prod_{i=1}^k d_i \cdot \left[ \sum_{i=1}^k d_i -k \right]
\end{equation}

Comment: @CarlaMascia Have you tried differentiating before evaluating at t=1?

Comment: @Alizter That is what I did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $$f_i(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{d_i-1}x^n=1+x+\cdots+x^{d_i-1}$$ and let $$\Psi=\prod_{j=1}^kf_j(t)$$
We have that $$\Phi=\frac\partial{\partial t}\Psi=\Psi\left(\sum^k_{j=1}\frac{f_j'(t)}{f_j(t)}\right)$$ Therefore $$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}\Psi=\frac\partial{\partial t}\Phi=\Psi'\left(\sum^k_{j=1}\frac{f_j'(t)}{f_j(t)}\right)+\Psi\left(\sum^k_{j=1}\frac{f_j'(t)}{f_j(t)}\right)=\Psi\left(\left(\sum^k_{j=1}\frac{f_j'(t)}{f_j(t)}\right)^2+\left(\sum^k_{j=1}\frac{f_j'(t)}{f_j(t)}\right)'\right)$$
Finally after simplification
$$\Psi\left(\left(\sum^k_{j=1}\frac{f_j'(t)}{f_j(t)}\right)^2+\sum^k_{j=1}\frac{f_j(t)f_j''(t)-f_j'(t)^2}{f_j(t)^2}\right)$$
The rest is just computations of the derivative at of $f_j$ at $t=1$ which should simplify nicely in terms of $d_j$.

---

Further Calculations
$$f_j(1)=d_j$$
$$f_j'(1)=\frac{d_j(d_j-1)}{2}$$
$$f_j''(1)=\frac{d_j(d_j-1)(d_j-2)}{3}$$
Thus you may finally plug and chug.

---

After the plug and chug I get $$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}\Psi=\left(\prod^k_{j=1}d_j\right)\left(\left(\sum^k_{j=1}\frac{d_j-1}2\right)^2-\sum^k_{j=1}\frac{(d_j-1)(d_j-5)}{2}\right)$$

Comment: I tried and I have found
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{12} \prod_{i=1}^k d_i \left[ 3 (\sum_{j=1}^k d_j - k)^2 + \sum_{j=1}^k d_i^2 - 6 \sum_{j=1}^k d_i + 5k \right]\end{equation}

Comment: I think you wanted to write
\begin{equation}
\left(\prod^k_{j=1}d_j\right)\left(\left(\sum^k_{j=1}\frac{d_j-1}2\right)^2-\sum^k_{j=1}\frac{(d_j-1)(d_j-5)}{12}\right)
\end{equation}

Comment: Actually, I need also the third derivative. Now I try to follow the same argument.

Answer (score 2):

This is basically the same calculation as Alitzer gives, but more readily generalized. The Leibniz rule (generalized to multiple derivatives & factors 
[[1]](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/616546/137524)) states that

$$\bigg(\prod_{j=1}^k f_j\bigg)^{\!(n)}=\sum_{\substack{c_1,\ldots,c_k\ge 0\\ c_1+\cdots+c_m=n}}\binom{n}{c_1,\cdots, c_k}f_1^{(c_1)}\cdots f_k^{(c_k)}$$ where $\binom{n}{c_1,\cdots, c_k}=n!/(c_1!\cdots c_k!)$ is a multinomial coefficient.

For the case of $n=2$ and $f_j=\sum_{k=0}^{d_j-1}t^k$ as above, this gives

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2} \left[ \prod_{j=1}^k (1+t+\dots+t^{d_j -1}) \right]
&=\sum_{c_1+\cdots +c_m=2}\binom{2}{c_1,\cdots,c_m}f_1^{(c_1)}\cdots f_k^{(c_k)}
\end{align}

Note that there are only two kinds of terms that show up in this sum: either exactly one of the $c's$ is 2, or some pair of them is 1 (with all others zero). So this simplifies to 
$$\sum_{i=1}^k\left( f_1\cdots f_i^{(2)}\cdots f_k\right)+\sum_{i<j}^k\left( f_1\cdots f_i^{(1)}\cdots f_j^{(1)}\cdots f_k\right)$$
which we now need to evaluate at $t=1$. Then

$$f_j|_{t=1}=d_j,
\hspace{.5cm} f^{(1)}_j|_{t=1}=\sum_{k=0}^{d_j-1} k = \frac{d_j(d_j-1)}{2},\\
\hspace{.5cm} f^{(2)}_j|_{t=1}=\sum_{k=0}^{d_j-1} k(k-1) = \frac{d_j(d_j-1)(d_j-2)}{3}.$$
Plugging these in and factoring a bit gives the final result as $$\left(\prod_{j=1}^m d_j\right)\left[\sum_{i=1}^{k}\frac{(d_i-1)(d_i-2)}{3}
+\sum_{i<j}\frac{(d_i-1)(d_j-1)}{4}\right]$$

Comment: For comparison with your first answer, note that $\sum_{j=1}^{k}\frac{d_j-1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}\left[\sum_{j=1}^k d_j-k\right]$. (Also, please look for typos. I'm prone to them.)

Answer (score -1):

I've cheated, I admit:

$$\frac{\partial ^2\left(\prod_j^k \sum _{d=0}^j t^d\right)}{\partial t^2}$$
at $t=1$ seems to equal

$$\frac{1}{144} (k-1) k (k+1) (9 k+22) (k+1)!$$

I can show you the cheat, but cannot provide a proof.

Comment: What is $n$????

Comment: @Alizter: should have used the same variables as in the question, sorry.

Comment: Maybe you should read the question a bit more carefully. Notice how your sum that you are differentiating is not the one the OP is asking for. The one the OP is asking for involves arbitrary integers.

Comment: @Carla Mascia: could you please elaborate what you intend by using the formulation $ (1+t+\dots+t^{d_j -1})$ ? Is there a set of exponents d_j such that d_0 =0 and d_1 =1, but the d_i are not necessarily [0,1,..,j] ?

Comment: $d_j$ is some integer. $j$ has nothing to do with the amount of terms

Comment: @WouterM. It's as Alizter wrote.